# What is a Ruled Surface of Type $ \mathbb{F}_{n}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ C $ be a smooth curve. I know that a surface $ X $ is said to be ruled over $ C, $ if there exists a smooth morphism $ \pi: X \rightarrow C $ such that each fibre of the morphism is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{P}^{1}. $

However, I don't know what it means to say that a surface is ruled of type $ \mathbb{F}_{n} $ for some $ n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}. $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supposed to be the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n))$, a ruled surface over $\mathbb{P}^1$.

For $n=0$ this is just $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and for $n =1$ this is $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up at one point.

I have seen both $\Sigma_n$ and $\mathbb{F}_n$ for Hirzebruch surfaces though.

Caution: Some authors also write $\mathbb{F}_n$ for taking the twist with the negative integer $-n$ instead of with $n$ even though that is less common.